# member initializer list not working

Tags: c++

I'm writing a matrix class:

```
template <typename T>
struct TMatrix44{
    TMatrix44(){
        // default construct an identity matrix
        memcpy(m, TMatrix44<T>::TheIdentity().m, sizeof(TMatrix44<T>));
    }
    TMatrix44(
    const T& m00, const T& m01, const T& m02, const T& m03,
    const T& m10, const T& m11, const T& m12, const T& m13,
    const T& m20, const T& m21, const T& m22, const T& m23,
    const T& m30, const T& m31, const T& m32, const T& m33)
    :   _00(m00), _01(m01), _02(m02), _03(m03),
        _10(m10), _11(m11), _12(m12), _13(m13),
        _20(m20), _21(m21), _22(m22), _23(m23),
        _30(m30), _31(m31), _32(m32), _33(m33)
    {
    }
    static const TMatrix44<T>& TheIdentity()
    {
        static TMatrix44<T> sm(
            1, 0, 0, 0,
            0, 1, 0, 0,
            0, 0, 1, 0,
            0, 0, 0, 1
            );
       return sm;
    }
    // non-standard extension: nameless union and struct
    union{
        T m[4][4];
        struct{
            T   _00, _01, _02, _03,
                _10, _11, _12, _13,
                _20, _21, _22, _23,
                _30, _31, _32, _33;
        };
    };
    // other contents...
};
```

When I use this template:

```
TMatrix44<float> m;
```

I found content of m was not identity matrix but all zeros, when I debug into the code I found the bug is in TheIdentity static method:

```
static const TMatrix44<T>& TheIdentity()
    {
        static TMatrix44<T> sm(
            1, 0, 0, 0,
            0, 1, 0, 0,
            0, 0, 1, 0,
            0, 0, 0, 1
            );
       return sm;   // sm here is still zero matrix, I have no idea what happened!!!
    }
```

Why didn't the sm constructed with identity? So weird!

Comment: It work for me in GCC 4.9.2.

Comment: How do you look at the elements to determine if they are empty? If you are using, e.g., the array within the `union` you'd have undefined behavior.

Comment: @DietmarKühl No, I write a test code to compare whether m._00 == 1, but it turns out that _00~_33 are all zeros

Comment: @NetVipeC Is there a bug with VS2013?